# How to do three left joins in SQL

Tags: sql, join, left-join

I know how to do a left join but when I add two more to the query. It gets a bit weird. So, here is the task. The original table, list20192, has 93 columns and 85,353 rows. However, the end user is not ok with it having no descriptive fields such as titles or descriptions. One field, naics, is a six-digit code and they want an industry title to go along with it. For the corresponding title that goes with naics code, 551114, one has to go to the indcodes table which has the following structure:

```
 state char(2)
 codetype   char(2)
 code      char(6)
 codetitle   varchar (115)

 GEOG Table
 state char (2)
 areatype char(2)
 area  (6)
 areaname varchar (254)
 areadesc varchar (254)
```

I am using the following query in an effort to attach the descriptive counterparts of the fields in list20192 to the end. The end result should be 96 columns and 85,353 rows. This query works but produces 6,800,277 rows which is far too many.

```
      Select list20192.*, geog.area, sizeclas.sizedesc
      from dbo.list20192
      left join dbo.indcodes on list20192.naics = indcodes.code
      left join dbo.sizeclas on list20192.sizeclass = sizeclas.sizeclass
      left join dbo.geog on list20192.area = geog.area
      where list20192.year = '2019' and list20192.qtr = '2'
```

The end result should look something like this. There are two rows with the sixth item being on the second row.

```
  naics    codetitle    sizeclass       sizedesc              area     

  541114   Management       22      400 to 499 employees    000025      

  areaname
    Pershing
```

Any ideas how I would adjust this query to not receive so many results? Now that the results show it appears that it is giving me a result for every area value in geog with no regard to state. I am in state 32. My original table list20192 only deals with state 32. For each state, there are many area values that could be identical. For instance, area 000003 in Nevada is Clark while 000003 in South Dakota is Beadle County

Comment: Your code looks fine.  The issue would seem to be bad join keys, but that is not really something that people not familiar with your data and help with.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, I am getting 6,800,277 rows as a result and only 2 extra columns instead of 3.

Comment: One thing that I'd use, for clarity *and* for expressing your joins, is table aliases, e.g. `from dbo.list20192 a`, `left join dbo.indcodes b on a.naics = b.code`, and so on.  When the `join .. on` syntax is used, the table-names are explicitly specified in the `on` clause and aliases are the easiest way to do that.  Use these aliases throughout the query.

Comment: Your probably getting duplicates, could add distinct, or find one that is duplicated and dig into each table to see if its bad data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proliferation of rows is undoubtedly being caused by having *multiple rows* in the various joined tables which match the requested join-key value.  A query will produce an output row for *every* matching combination:  for example, a join of a table with 2 matching keys on one side and 5 on the other will produce 2*5 = 10 result rows.

One easy way to find out might be to add `JOIN` clauses one at a time.

Without having any idea, of course, what your data looks like, I'd probably finger that `geog` table.  *(The other two just look to me like lookup-tables.)*

The `DISTINCT` clause can filter out duplicates, but note that this can be expensive.  Maybe you need to be more specific with one or more of these tables . . .

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: @PM77-1, How it works is that state, areatype, and area are a composite (or compound) primary key. Area is not unique in the sense that an area value of 000003 could appear as many as 52 other times (50 states plus guam and the virgin islands).

Comment: @Tim That's is the exact reason your JOIN results in so many rows.

Comment: @PM77-1, do you have any suggestions on how to get it to act like a VLOOKUP in excel and only join/attach the corresponding values?

Comment: I gave a best answer but honestly, I had to abandon this method and go back to using excel and Vlookups. I thought that using Joins was going to be rather simple but it was not.